# Open Atrium: Customizing user badge

Tags: theming, distributions

In the Default installation of Open Atrium, Under the navigation bar, on the right side you will see User Badge. For Anonymous user it shows Login text with link and for the authenticated user it shows Username text with image and link and sub menu shows Dashboard, Edit Profile & Logout (all with their associated links respectively).

I want to customize the user badge when user is logged in. I want to add/delete option under the drop-down. Is there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 1):

check the hook

```
function hook_preprocess_oa_user_badge(&$vars) {
  if (user_access('YOUR PERMISSION')) {
    $vars['links']['#links']['YOUR BUNDLE'] = array(
      'title' => t('ITEM TITLE'),
      'href' => 'ITEM URL',
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In oa_dashboard.module:

```
function template_preprocess_oa_user_badge(&$vars)
```

In oa_users.module:

```
function oa_users_build_user_details($user, $image_style = 'oa_small_thumbnail')
```